# Hadoop streaming with HBase as data sink

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-streaming

Our research group has Hadoop and HBase set up and running.

Recently I am using Hadoop streaming (only mappers) to process data, and I wish to use HBase as the data sink. I feel that I can set -outputformat to TableOutFormat. But after searching web for some time, I found out that specific operations can take much time to figure out.

Below is my trial:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -outputformat HBaseLibDir/TableOutFormat \
    -mapper myMapperScript \
    -numReduceTasks 0
```

Can someone with experience teach me how to do this? including what to change in myMapperScript, and the parameters that passed in to initialize the streaming job.

Comment: AS you are using streaming, which language are you working on.

Comment: @Ramzy I am working on Python, but I think it doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: Well in java, there is a good way to use Hbase as sink with map reduce. Since you are using streaming, the script you are talking about should have the mapping between the fields in your input file to the column qualifiers of Hbase(as part of Put). So I think you should use that script for the mapping in your language(may be python as you said).

Comment: My idea is that if I can set up parameters in streaming job properly (HBase library, table name, etc) and output key-value pairs according to the format as it requires (for instance: Rowkey\tColumn\tValue), then HBase can pick up the output and put them in tables. (That would be great!)

Comment: It would be great really, but there should be some code to match the field to column qualifier as a set of params could not do it. Thats th reason the script is for i suppose. I am from java back ground, so can help you in concepts only :) . I assume you are refering to [this](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/wanpark/20081113/1226555456). But that is third party i suppose. Verify if its supported

Comment: @Ramzy You are right, what I need is the 'match' function. I am wondering if HBase natively supports this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from HBase mailing list:

> Cannot do Hadoop streaming output (directly) to HBase. Use REST/Thrift
>   API instead.